# Is it possible to logout to any other DE without close any running application?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments

Refer to my title, is it possible to do that? Let say im on Unity with running VPS on Virtual Box, but i want to switch to Gnome without shutdown my VPS and run back on Gnome. Is it possible?

Please advice.

Comment: The DE is in itself a running application, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Im on unity with running virtual box as server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open n sessions with the same user :

you could install Xephyr o Xnest(older) and then open a new Xsession in a window (like a Picture In Picture):

`startx /usr/bin/startkde -- /usr/bin/Xephyr :2`

or

`startx /usr/bin/gnome-session -- /usr/bin/Xephyr :2`

or CTRL-ALT-F1, login and open a new X-window session:

`starx /usr/bin/gnome-session -- :2` or any other session manager or command, ie xterm

And move between sessions with CTRL-ALT-F7,F8
Just beware of RAM :)

Comment: You cannot move an application from one session to another, however, and the sessions will collide with each other on some matter, so they won't be the full experience, or you may run into other problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to switch the environment out from underneath running applications, as your current user. You can however log in to an additional session as a different user, with the "switch user" feature from the locked screen unlock display, or the session indicator (gear icon in the upper right under Unity).